# About the explanation of testing and measurement of hash function at wikipedia

Tags: hash, hashtable, chi-squared, hash-function

I'm studying about hash function with wikipedia and here is the explanation of testing and measurement of hash function's uniformity.

here is the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Testing_and_measurement)

The chi-square test is mentioned in the description, but I do not understand how this formula relates to the chi-square test and how it was derived.

what is the relation of formula and chi-square test?

Comment: If someone want to see an answer to this question, [please refer to this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/532701/326682)